# Node.js EJS express-validator for each

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm going absolutely nuts trying to get this done with ejs. handlebars. no problem. but forcing to learn ejs.

What I am trying to do is get an error object and loop through the object and print out each message as a li.

```
   <% if (errors !== undefined){ %>
     <p>there are errors on page</p>
   <% for each(error in errors){ %>
     <li><%= error.msg%></li>
   <% }) %>
   <% }  %>
```

I have tried many different ways to get the data to display, but I cannot seem to find my hangup. How I should get each object's `msg`?

The above code is just a fraction of the code. [Whole code](https://github.com/4T0M1Cdevsec/node-mongo-mailchimp-prelaunch)

EDIT:
Deleted information from post as it no longer pertains to my issue.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Error is just a iterator, if you want to print use errors[error].msg

Comment: @subrahmanyabhat 
Original code results in compiling error(syntax is wrong)
trying errors[error].msg results in "error is undefined".
I think i have found another way to get the result i want, although my code won't be as dry.

Comment: Did you check your errors object ?  Is that in proper object format ? Convert it to proper json format and print it,

Comment: @subrahmanyabhat edited OP. It does comeback in json and is a valid object. When i show the object on my page the data is returned as 'object'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my error(s) [pun intended]

1. I was using .mapped which makes the data an object.. i needed to do .array
2. even with the object, the js I wanted to run does not work with objects (or at least i cant figure out how to loop through the objects specific properties).
3. Correct syntax for the code I wanted to run is as follows:

   ```
     <% if (errors !== undefined){ %>
     <p>there are errors on page</p>
     <% for (const error of errors){ %>
     <li><%= error.msg %> </li>
     <% } %>
     <% }  %>
   ```